# “It” vs. “that”

Tags: grammaticality, word-choice, pronouns, relative-pronouns

Is this sentence correct?

> I did **it** yesterday, but I’m not going to do **it** again.

I’m not sure about it. Should I replace “it” with “that”?

> 1. I did **it** yesterday, but I’m not going to do **it** again.
> 2. I did **it** yesterday, but I’m not going to do **that** again.
> 3. I did **that** yesterday, but I’m not going to do **it** again.
> 4. I did **that** yesterday, but I’m not going to do **that** again.

Are all versions correct?

Comment: Both sentences are correct. But if for a formal use, you'd better have "going to" instead of "gonna".

Comment: @Laure FYI I've edited the question to show 4 possibilities and rewritten "gonna".

Comment: This is a great question. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All four sound natural to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want option 1) or option 3). If I were going to say option 3), I would place the emphasis on Yesterday, as in, "I've already tried that; I did it yesterday; it didn't work; I'm not doing it again." The first option is more neutral. Options 2 and 4 sound odd to me.

Comment: Is it correct to replace "again" with "anymore"? Does it still make sense? Thank You for Your help guys. It means a lot to me :).

Answer (score 0):

I feel that in most of the cases, *it* and *that* are interchangeable. However, in some cases, they are strictly not! For instance, a slogan *Just do it!* won't sound proper with *Just do that!* The same thing may go for an idiom for encouragement *You can do it!*

If I dig it further for **a subtle difference,** the word *that* refers to anything that's mentioned or understood, whereas *it* may refer to anything which is previously mentioned or understood.

Broadly, all sentences seem okay but still, I'd prefer using *it* for the latter clause when *that* is already mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

The word *that* is generally used for specific objects.

> For example: That car belongs to me.

Or its used when you're comparing two objects.

> For example: Red Bull's car is faster than that of Ferrari.

*(See how I used "it" there)*.

Comment: you din' use *it* anywhere!